# Is there a way to open a U.S. bank account for my LLC remotely?

Tags: united-states, banking, limited-liability-company, international, online-banking

I'm operating a company remotely — I'm not in the U.S.

Is there a way to open a bank account without going to the U.S.? I've called a few banks and most of them require myself to go the a branch in the U.S. Wells Fargo allow us to open the bank account remotely, but it doesn't allow wire transfer online.

Any other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

Although there may be red tape for a business account, Alliant Credit Union offers completely online signup and their representatives are reachable by email. You'll probably need to send in the LLC articles this way

http://www.alliantcu.com/checking-accounts.html (as pointed out by @littleadv this site defaults to "personal checking" accounts, there is a business checking tab which doesn't generate a direct link, some might miss that)

And even if there are a ton of regulations that some pencil pushers at larger banks anecdotally cite (without citing), there will be enough banks that don't care. Good Luck

Comment: I've called them and they are restricted to some specific industries, so we are not be able to apply. Any other option?

Comment: @diegows other credit unions. also your LLC can designate a nominee or employee or nominal partner (or anyone really) to open a bank account in person with the LLC's documents - this will have to go in your operating agreement or something - and then immediately resign.. after you have the online banking, debit card and checks of course

Comment: "... and then immediately resign..." Sounds to me like one side or the other of that plan would be just begging to be scammed or liable for more than they intended. I wouldn't touch that kind of deal.

Comment: @keshlam eh any employee has the same capability, there are reputable companies that offer this in practically every jurisdiction

Comment: I still wouldn't touch it. Your milage will vary.

Comment: What is credit union? And why they allow this sort of thing?

Comment: @JimThio In 2016 I would point to Stripe's ATLAS service.

Comment: what is that? What is stripe's atlas service?

Comment: @JimThio sets up LLCs for non Americans and gives them a US bank account

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mercury](https://mercury.com/). It's a [YC](https://ycombinator.com)-backed company.

They opened an account for our Delaware C-corp, which we established remotely via a registered agent.